# Pandas appends duplicate rows even though if statement shouldn't be triggered

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have many csv files that only have one row of data. I need to take data from two of the cells and put them into a master csv file ('new_gal.csv'). Initially this will only contain the headings, but no data.

```
#The file I am pulling from:
 file_name = "N4261_pacs160.csv"
#I have the code written to separate gal_name, cat_name, and cat_num (N4261, pacs, 160)
```

An example of the csv is given here. I am trying to pull "flux" and "rms" from this file. (Sorry it isn't aligned nicely; I can't figure out the formatting).

```
name  band  ra  dec  raerr  decerr  flux  snr  snrnoise  stn  rms  strn  fratio  fwhmxfit  fwhmyfit  flag_elong  edgeflag  flag_blend  warmat 
 obsid  ssomapflag  dist  angle
HPPSC160A_J121923.1+054931  red  184.846389  5.8254  0.000151  0.00015 
 227.036  10.797  21.028  16.507  13.754  37.448  1.074  15.2  11  0.7237 
 f  0  f  1342199758  f  1.445729  296.577621
```

I read this csv and pull the data I need

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as table:
    reader = csv.reader(table, delimiter=',')
    read = iter(reader)
    next(read)
    for row in read:
        fluxP = row[6]
        errP = row[10]
#Open the master csv with pandas
df = pd.read_csv('new_gal.csv')
```

The master csv file has format:

```
Galaxy  Cluster Mult. Detect.   LumDist z   W1  W1 err  W2  W2 err  W3  W3 err  W4  W4 err  70  70 err  100 100 err 160 160 err 250 250 err 350 350 err 500 500 err
```

The main problem I have, is that I want to search the "Galaxy" column in the 'new_gal.csv' for the galaxy name. If it is not there, I need to add a new row with the galaxy name and the flux and error measurement. When I run this multiple times, I get duplicate rows even though I have the append command nested in the if statement. I only want it to append a new row if the galaxy name is not already there; otherwise, it should only change the values of the flux and error measurements for that galaxy.

```
if cat_name == 'pacs':
    if gal_name not in df["Galaxy"]:
        df = df.append({"Galaxy": gal_name}, ignore_index=True)
        if cat_num == "70":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["70"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["70 err"]] = errP
        elif cat_num == "100":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["100"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["100 err"]] = errP
        elif cat_num == "160":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["160"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["160 err"]] = errP
    else:
        if cat_num == "70":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["70"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["70 err"]] = errP
        elif cat_num == "100":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["100"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["100 err"]] = errP
        elif cat_num == "160":
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["160"]] = fluxP
            df.loc[df.Galaxy == gal_name, ["160 err"]] = errP
```

After running the code 5 times with the same file, I have 5 identical lines in the table.

Comment: Can you re-edit your post and do 2 things:  1.  show the code where you are reading the individual .csv files and making the merged one and 2.  include a copy of a couple of the individual .csv files so we can see structure and content.  All of the stuff you included above is irrelevant to the problem which you are having.  Take `pandas` out of the loop for now and let's see if we can get a properly constructed .csv file setup!

Comment: The formatting of the .csv  doesn't look very nice. I only care about flux = 227.036, and rms = 13.754. It seems that the if statement: if gal_name not in df["Galaxy"], is the cause. I think it always says that is true even when it already added the galaxy name to the column.

Comment: OK.  Several problems...  But I (or others) can probably help.  First off, your .csv file is not well formed...there are no commas!  when you open those files in a text editor, do they have commas or not (do not use Excel for this yet)?  Second, if you got all of your individual .csv files into one master that had everything in it, how would you find yourself in the case that you look up a "Galaxy" and there is missing info?  Presumably it is all in the master .csv file.  Why is there data missing and where would you get it from?

Comment: Also...  (after re-reading)...  Are you trying to merge in data into the master which already has a bunch of fields in it and you want to add from the individual files or are you building the "master" from scratch using the smaller files?

Comment: The first problem you mention is my fault. I copied and pasted from excel. It does have commas if I open in a text editor. Your next comment is what I was trying to accomplish. I have a script that uses selenium to automatically search databases and download the .csv for PACS 70,100,160 and SPIRE 250,350,500. Each of those csv files have a lot of extra information I don't need. The master file already has the headings, but is otherwise blank and I need to fill in certain values. My plan was to use a foreach loop in my terminal and run it for *.csv in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got something that'll work after tinkering with it this morning...

Couple points...  You shouldn't incrementally build in pandas...get the data setup done externally then do 1 build.  In what I have below, I'm building a big dictionary from the small csv files and then using merge to put that together with the master file.

If your .csv files aren't formatted properly, you can either try to replace the split character below or switch over to `csv` reader that is a bit more powerful.

You should put all of the smaller .csv files in a folder called 'orig_data' to make this work.

### main prog

```
# galaxy compiler
import os, re
import pandas as pd

# folder location for the small .csvs, NOT the master
data_folder = 'orig_data'  # this folder should be in same directory as program

result = {}
splitter = r'(.+)_([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.'  # regex to break up file name into 3 groups

for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    file_data = {}
    # split up the filename and process
    galaxy, cat_name, cat_num = re.match(splitter, file).groups()
    #print(galaxy, cat_name, cat_num)
    with open(os.path.join(data_folder, file), 'r') as src:
        src.readline()   # read the header and disregard it
        data = src.readline().replace(' ','').strip().split(',') # you can change the split char
        flux = float(data[2])
        rms = float(data[3])
    err_tag = cat_num + ' err'
    file_data = {   'cat_name': cat_name, 
                    cat_num:    flux,
                    err_tag:    rms}
    result[galaxy] = file_data

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
df2.index.rename('galaxy', inplace=True)

# check the resulting build!
#print(df2)

# build master dataframe
master_df = pd.read_csv('master_data.csv')
#print(master_df.head())

# merge the 2 dataframes on galaxy name.  See the dox on merge for other
# options and whether you want an "outer" join or other type of join...
master_df = master_df.merge(df2, how='outer', on='galaxy')

# convert boolean flags properly
conv = {'t': True, 'f': False}
master_df['flag_nova'] = master_df['flag_nova'].map(conv).astype('bool')

print(master_df)
print()
print(master_df.info())
print()
print(master_df.describe())
```

### example data files in `orig_data` folder

filename: A99_dbc100.csv

```
band,weight,flux,rms
junk, 200.44,2e5,2e-8
```

filename: B250_pacs100.csv

```
band,weight,flux,rms
nada,2.44,19e-5, 74
```

...etc.

### example master csv

```
galaxy,color,stars,flag_nova
A99,red,15,f
B250,blue,4e20,t
N1000,green,3e19,f
X99,white,12,t
```

## Result:

```
  galaxy  color         stars  ...  200 err           100       100 err
0    A99    red  1.500000e+01  ...      NaN  200000.00000  2.000000e-08
1   B250   blue  4.000000e+20  ...      NaN       0.00019  7.400000e+01
2  N1000  green  3.000000e+19  ...     88.0           NaN           NaN
3    X99  white  1.200000e+01  ...      NaN           NaN           NaN

[4 rows x 9 columns]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 9 columns):
galaxy       4 non-null object
color        4 non-null object
stars        4 non-null float64
flag_nova    4 non-null bool
cat_name     3 non-null object
200          1 non-null float64
200 err      1 non-null float64
100          2 non-null float64
100 err      2 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(1), float64(5), object(3)
memory usage: 292.0+ bytes
None

              stars        200  200 err            100       100 err
count  4.000000e+00        1.0      1.0       2.000000  2.000000e+00
mean   1.075000e+20  1900000.0     88.0  100000.000095  3.700000e+01
std    1.955121e+20        NaN      NaN  141421.356103  5.232590e+01
min    1.200000e+01  1900000.0     88.0       0.000190  2.000000e-08
25%    1.425000e+01  1900000.0     88.0   50000.000143  1.850000e+01
50%    1.500000e+19  1900000.0     88.0  100000.000095  3.700000e+01
75%    1.225000e+20  1900000.0     88.0  150000.000048  5.550000e+01
max    4.000000e+20  1900000.0     88.0  200000.000000  7.400000e+01
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your "splitter" variable looks much more efficient than what I was trying to do. Why do you say not to build incrementally in pandas? Is a time/efficiency thing?

Comment: yes.  It is very inefficient...if that matters in your use case.  Also it leads to fairly weird constructs (like what you had) that are very fragile to the names & constants that you use to set it up.  If the info is in the files, putting it into named dictionaries (like I did with `file_data` is easy and not fragile to changes.  It isn't clear why you need the "master" at all if it is just headings and all that stuff would be blank.  I think the first part of my code before the merge with the master probably does what you want unless I'm missing something about the empty master.